# Testing API's with certificates

Tags: api, postman, certificate

I'm somewhat inexperienced with API's. I've been screwing around and somehow managed to get them working.

My question is relating to an API that was working before. It is a POST, with a non-variable URL (i.e. **not** https://url/call?id={id}), and with a JSON body request.

The call is secured with a certificate that was generated using openssl. The certificate has since expired, and following the steps exactly as detailed in the API documentation. I have tested the files, with the developers of the API on a screen share, on Postman using the pem, key and pfx files as Postman specifies.

But our system needs a CER file, that is generated from the pfx file by our Platform's specialists - and that is the only part where I have no interaction with any of the files.

On Postman the call is successful, but when the CER file is generated and installed, it doesn't work.

Is there another app similar to Postman, but where I can use the CER file as generated by our Platform, or perhaps generate my own CER file, test it and install and then use.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pfx or Key files contains private key that is required to sign API request but CER file does not contain private key.

For any more details, please share the API specifications so the mechanism to achieve requirement can be devised.